# how to make the data ascending/descending using vue js datatable (parent-child)

Tags: laravel, vue.js

My question is about the parent-child DataTable used in `vue.js`, I want to show the data in the descending format. But it's just allowing the filter for `columnname:name`.

```
this.datatable = ele.DataTable( {

             "data": [],
             "columns": [

             {  
                "className":'details-control',
                "orderable":false,
                "data":"name",
                "defaultContent": '',
             },

             ]

            } );
```

here above in data the name is passed, its just filtering through the name. I also want it according to one more column in my database table.so it should display the name also in descending format.

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but in your Laravel controller, you can sort the data as your fetching it from the database. For example ```$user = DB::table('users')->latest()->first();```

Comment: i done this in the query,and the data coming in that array is also coming as I want.Then i have pased this data to vue,and while viewing the data its not coming in the descendingh order.